# Angular 2 http - filter the observable before returning it

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

In service I have this defined:

```
getAllHTTP(): Observable<IUser[]> {
   return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users`)
              .map(res => res.json())
              .catch(err => Observable.throw(err));
}
```

and in the component:

```
ngOnInit() {
   const self = this;
   this._uService.getAllHTTP().subscribe(
      function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        self.listOfUsers = data
      },
      (error) => console.error(error)
   );
}
```

So now I wanted to filter the data before passing the observable to component and I did this:

```
  getAllHTTP(): Observable<IUser[]> {
     return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users`)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .filter(<IUser>(x) => x.id > 2)
                .catch(err => Observable.throw(err));
  }
```

and it doesn't work. The `x` in filter is an actual array, not an item in the array. This is really odd and I think it has nothing to do with RXjs, because it works like it's suppose to in this example: http://jsbin.com/nimejuduso/1/edit?html,js,console,output

So I did some digging and apparently I should be using flatMap. OK, I did that, replaced `map` with `flatMap` but now I get this error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'

So apparently when I subscribe, I used to get an array and now I get one object at a time... Why is Angular2 behaving like that? Or is this RXjs after all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are applying a filter on the observable stream, thus filtering events within the stream and not elements within the array which in this case is a single event in the stream.

What you need to do is:

```
getAllHTTP(): Observable<IUser[]> {
     return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users`)
                .map(res => res.json()
                            .filter(<IUser>(x) => x.id > 2))
                .catch(err => Observable.throw(err));
}
```

The example you linked is working like that because `Observable.from` is creating a sequence of values for the observable, rather than a singe value being the whole array. This is why the `Observable.filter` is working as it does, because the array elements are passing by one at a time. See more details in the [docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/from.md).

Comment: well thanks for the explanation, I understand a bit what's going on. So `map` in this case is not working upon array, but upon observable? It's confusing because observable functions are named exactly like functions for array. filter, map... obviously they behave differently. Could I solve my issues with flatMap?

Comment: If you are expecting a filtered array in your subscribe function you should not use flatMap. It is true that the namings can be confusing, and it is important to make sure you apply filterings etc to either the observable, or the observed value depending on what your needs are. [flatMap](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) will cause your subscribe function to be called once for each item in your array, which does not seem to be your goal in this case.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what's going on currently. when I subscribe to flatMap, I get all the correct objects, but they stream one after another. I wanted an array. If I may ask just a follow up question, when would the flatMap be useful in Angular2 http services?

Comment: There's many cases where flatMap can be useful. It is particularly useful when chaining together a sequence of requests where each request is depending on the previous result. Similarly to the `Promise.then` chaining pattern in the world of promises.

Comment: Thank you, considering the corresponding explanation I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are asking for a list of user, hence the array. If I got you correctly, you want all users with id > 2:

```
return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users`)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map((users: Array<IUser>) => users.filter(user => user.id > 2)
            .catch(err => Observable.throw(err));
```