# Angular 8: Get values without subscription to an observable

Tags: angular, components, observable

These are the two methods that I need to subscribe to in various parts of my application:

```
  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.url);
}

  getProductsByIds(ids: number[]): Observable<Products[]> {
    return this.getProducts()
      .map(products => products.filter(products => ids.includes(product.id)));
}
```

This works fine for most of my compoments, but in one component, I know the`id`-s beforehand and just want to display 4 products with id-s 1, 2, 9, 18. I want to call the method like so: `getProductsByIds([1, 2, 9, 18])`). I only know how to subscribe to these two observables, but how can I just get these 4 products once and for all (without the need for a stream of values)? I must have missed some basic lecture..

Comment: Is this values are kind of static data?

Comment: Yes, the products are the same all the time, with the same id-s, I'm just filtering them mostly in the app.

Comment: dose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753212/angular-2-http-filter-the-observable-before-returning-it is answer of your question

Comment: Thank you all for your anwsers! Plochie, thank you, that makes a lot of sense. Right now i'm doing all the subscriptions in the components (not in the service), so I hope that it will not be too much to refactor everything. Since I have a lot of other filtering methods (for example, based on different type of product/search/favorite/etc.), I must think a little how I'd be able to re-work this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the function in `service` constructor, and after result obtain, set that result to `class` level variable `staticProducts: Products[]`.

Whenever you want to use the `staticProducts`, inject the service and use directly by `this.demoService.staticProducts`

**Service**

```js
@Injectable()
export class DemoService {

  staticProducts: Products[];

  constructor(.....) {
    // get static data on startup
    this.getProductsByIds([1, 2, 9, 18]);
  }

  getProductsByIds(ids: number[]): Observable<Products[]> {
    return this.getProducts()
      .map(products => products.filter(products => ids.includes(product.id)))
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.staticProducts = res;
      });
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get some values and stick them into a variable without an Observable. 
 From your component you could just call getProductByIds like this:

```
service.getProductByIds([1,2,9.8]).take(1).subscribe(x => {
   this.variableWithProducts = x;
});
```